# MySQL Design for multiple search condition

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am design a Table where multiple search conditions for multiple column are possible. If a new feature arrives, new column keep adding in a Table.

Instead of adding a column everytime, I would like to design a property kind of Table where the column name can be stored as KEY and value column value as VALUE. It is easy to filter multiple search condition.

Table1 sample entries

```
Emp1 Male 23 
Emp2 Female 25
Emp3 Female 27
Emp4 Male 29
```

Table2 Sample Entries

```
ID   : KEY  : VALUE
Emp1 : 5001 : 20
Emp1 : 5002 : 22
Emp1 : 6001 : 0
Emp1 : 6002 : 2
```

I would like to get the search results by applying joins and conditions as t2.KEY!=5001 . But this will provide results by matching the conditions of other 3 entries of ID:Emp1. I would like to not get search results if t2.KEY!=5001 and get results of only Emp2,Emp3,Emp4.

Comment: I don't understand why you want a key/value table instead of (a) new columns, or (b) new tables for each property. You've already seen how your chosen approach leads to trouble and confusion. Is this a hard requirement? Why not use a more conventional database layout?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: (a) new columns >> Table1 has 22 columns, keep adding columns to this will have default entries for most the rows which I try to avoid it for saving small amount of disk space :-)
(b) adding new table for each property would be good idea?

Comment: Read about EAV -- key-value schema has a lot of problems.

Comment: @RickJames , Reading about EAV gives me some details. Thanks for sharing this. I am planning to go with adding columns in Table2 for all searchable items instead of row based.

Comment: See also `FULLTEXT` indexing if the "search" is for "words".

Comment: Sure, will read about FULLTEXT :-)